# Python Multiprocessing: Only one process is running

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I am trying to spawn multiple parallel processes using the Python multiprocessing module. Basically, I did something like

```
pool = Pool(30)
results = [pool.apply_async(foo, (trainData, featureVector, terms, selLabel)) for selLabel in selLabels]
for r in results:
    tmp = r.get()
    modelFiles[tmp[0]] = tmp[1]
```

30 processes are spawned, however, it seems most of the processes have been put into sleep while only one process is actually running. Below is what I get from ps:

```
PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND

31267 74.6  2.4 7125412 6360080 pts/1 Sl+  13:06  24:25  \_ python2.6 /home/PerlModules/Python/DoOVA.py

31427 27.4  2.3 6528532 6120904 pts/1 R+   13:20   5:18      \_ python2.6 /home/PerlModules/Python/DoOVA.py

31428  0.0  1.3 4024724 3617016 pts/1 S+   13:20   0:00      \_ python2.6 /home/PerlModules/Python/DoOVA.py

31429  0.0  1.3 4024724 3617016 pts/1 S+   13:20   0:00      \_ python2.6 /home/PerlModules/Python/DoOVA.py

31430  0.0  1.3 4024724 3617016 pts/1 S+   13:20   0:00      \_ python2.6 /home/PerlModules/Python/DoOVA.py
```

`DoOVA.py` is the script I am running. Most of them have a status `S+`.

Could anyone give me some clue about what's the problem? I know the input arguement `featureVector` is pretty large in size, say around 300MB. Would that be a problem? The machine I am running on have several TB of memory though.

foo does something like:

```
def foo(trainData, featureVector, terms, selLabel, penalty):
    outputFile = 'train_'+selLabel+'.dat'
    annotation = dict()
    for id in trainData:
        if trainData[id] == selLabel:
            annotation[id] = '1'
        else:
            annotation[id] = '-1'
    try:
        os.mkdir(selLabel)
        os.chdir(selLabel)
    except OSError:
        os.chdir(selLabel)
    ###Some more functions, which involves a command line call through call from subprocess module
    os.chdir('../')
    return (selLabel, 'SVM_' + selLabel + '.model')
```

All other input arguments are small in size. And the machine has at least 100 cpus. In every run, it takes the script a long time even before any directory was created, although there is no significant computation happened in foo before os.mkdir()

Comment: You're not showing the function you're trying to run concurrently. Also, you should look at `map` for a way to more convenientely spread the data across your workers.

Comment: If `foo` completes quickly, it's possible that one process will end up always winning the race to pull the next work item off the queue that's internally used to distribute work to the processes in the `Pool`. Also, how many cores does the system have? How big is `selLabels`?

Comment: You also don't want to be passing something as large as `featureVector` between processes more than you have to. You'd be better off passing it to all the children once, at `Pool` creation time,  using the `initializer`/`initargs` arguments.

Comment: @NilsWerner, I added the function. Is there any performance difference betweeen appl_async and map?

Comment: @dano, foo definite takes a lot of time to finish. I passed featureVector as an input argument to every process. I don't think there is a redundancy. Is there any performance benefit using initargs?

Comment: @BinZhou If there are more than 30 items in `selLabels`, then it would be more efficient to pass `featureVector` via `initargs`, because you won't have to pass it to the same `Process` more than once. Going back to your original question, can you add a `print(multiprocessing.current_process())` to the top of `foo`, so you can exactly how often each process is running `foo`?

Comment: Have you checked if `foo` runs fine without the multiprocessing stuff? I am not exactly sure what you're doing there but `for id in trainData: if trainData[id] == selLabel:` seems wrong to me. `for i in x` already gives back the item and not the index, however you are trying to use the item as an index for itself afterwards.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As the comments indicate you want to pass `featureVector` using the `initializer` and `initargs` arguments to `Pool`. On Unix-type systems this will result in a massive performance increase (even if there's only 1 item in `selLabels`) because the value will passed to the child process essentially for free using `os.fork`. Otherwise each time `foo` is called, `featureVector` will get pickled by the parent process, passed through a pipe and unpickled by the child process. This will take a long time, and will essentially serialize all the child processes since they'll be waiting for the parent process to pickle and send a copy of `featureVector` for each call, one by one.

Since there's some confusion about what I'm talking about above, here's a bit longer explanation of what's happening in your code as its currently written:

When you create the `Pool` object, immediately 30 worker processes are created, all children of the main process which created the `Pool` object. In order to communitcate with each child process a pipe is a created. This pipe allows two way communication between the parent process and the child processes. The parent uses the pipe to instruct the child process what to do, and the children uses the pipe to notify the parent of the result of any operations.

When you first call `pool.apply_async` the parent process sends a command through the pipe instructing a child process to execute the `foo` function using the arguments supplied.  Since one of the arguments is huge, 300MB, this ends up taking a very long time. The parent process has to pickle the object. This converts the object (and everything it references) into a byte stream that can be sent through a pipe.

Since the pipe can only hold about 64k (Linux default), and you're sending much more than that, this effectively synchronizes the parent and one of the child processes. The parent process can only send the arguments as fast the child process can receive and unpickle them, and child process can only receive the arguments as fast as the parent pickle and send them. While this is going on all the other child process have to wait. The parent process can only send a command to one child process a time.

Once the parent process has finished sending all the arguments for the first call of `foo`, it can then move on to sending a command to call `foo` for a second time. Very soon after that, once the child process has finished receiving all the arguments, the child will call `foo`. (This is why it takes a long time before any directory is created, it takes a long time before `foo` is even called.) After `foo` returns the child process will then wait for the parent process to send another command. If `foo` itself takes a short enough amount of time to execute, it's possible that same child process that received the first command to call `foo` will also receive the second command to call `foo`.

Unless `foo` itself takes a long time to execute, as long or longer than it takes to send `featureVector` over the pipe, then you'll be effectively limited to just one child process executing at time. The parent process will be trying to command the child processes to call `foo` as fast as it can, but because `featureVector` is so big, it can only do so at a very slow rate. Once it's done sending the command to one process to call `foo`, the previous process it commanded to call `foo` will already finished calling `foo` long ago. There will be little or no overlap between running child processes.

In order to fixed the performance problem in your code you'll want to do something like this:

```
def child_initialize(_trainData, _featureVector, _terms):
     global trainData, featureVector, terms
     trainData = _trainData
     featureVector = _featureVector
     terms = _terms

def foo(selLabel):
     ...

pool = Pool(30, initialize = child_initialize, initargs = (trainData, featureVector, terms))
results = [pool.apply_async(foo, (selLabel,)) for selLabel in selLabels]
```

This code also passes `trainData` and `term` using `initargs` on the assumption they don't change either.

While this should result in a huge performance improvement, and allow the child processes to run in parallel, it's unlikely to mean that that child processes will show up in `ps` in the runable state all that more often. Your example `foo` function looks like it'll be spending most of its time waiting for the "command line call" to finish.

Comment: You really won't get much performance increase from `os.fork`, even on Unix, because any interaction with `featureVector` in the child processes will increase its internal reference count, which means the object will have to be copied in each child.

Comment: @dano Increasing the reference count will only cause the 4K page containing the reference count to be copied. No other part of the dictionary object itself will be copied. Any values fetched from the dictionary will also have their reference count incremented, but only at most 4K per value fetched. Even if the entire 300MB dictionary gets copied this way, it'll still be **massively** faster than **pickling**, **writing**, **reading** and **unpickling** the 300MB `featureVector` just once, let alone countless times.

Comment: @dano And of course this answers the original poster's question. The reason why the child processes are sleeping is because they're all blocked waiting for the parent process to send the arguments to `foo`.

Comment: I do agree that this is faster than pickling/unpickling the entire object, and concede that the wording of my original comment was too strong; it's definitely faster to use `initargs`, but saying that passing the object via `os.fork` is "essentially free" is not quite accurate, since a good chunk of the object's size may end up getting copied to each child, even if the OP never actually modifies the container or its contents.

Comment: Also, I didn't read the OP's edit to his original question, or the last paragraph of your answer, carefully enough. I agree that some combination of `featureVector` being very slow to copy, the OP not waiting long enough to check the CPU time of each worker, and the fact that each worker needs to wait on subprocess to run (which takes no CPU time), likely does address the original question.

Comment: @dano I've updated my answer with a more detailed explanation of why only one child process is running at time.

Comment: @RossRidge That's a great answer and explained my problem as well. I was puzzled as to why only one python process -out of 32, since I have a 32 cpu Linux machine- was running at a time. In my case, the file size passed to child processes was ~1.7Mb (>65k Ross explained above).

Comment: That fixed the problem for me on Linux.  Note that the code example has a typo.  `initialize` should be `initializer`.